# Strange IIS behaviour. It send data to local requests very slow

Tags: networking, performance, .net-framework, asp.net, iis-8

We have a `C#` `mvc` project that runs fine on several computers. On one PC I have a strange issue and at first I thought it was coding related, hence a question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43585637/434949). But after some tests, it doesn't seem to be coding related.

The project runs on a local IIS on windows 10 and has several controllers (pages). When I browse to the homepage (and several other pages) on the same computer, it takes about 2minutes to receive the first byte, every time. Other pages of the project run fast.

Naturally I thought it was because of the code on those pages, but debugging showed all the pages (fast an slow) hit the last event (`Application_PreSendRequestContent`) within 100ms. After that it should start sending data.

If i access this website from another computer via network, it works as it should. Even when the same computer is still waiting for the first byte of the homepage, the other computer can request the same page directly.

Overview:

- PC 1: windows 10 / IIS
- PC 1: Request homepage on PC1: 2minutes to first byte
- PC 1: Request page X1 on PC1: 2minutes to first byte
- PC 1: Request page X2 on PC1: instant result
- PC 1: Request page X3 on PC1: instant result
- PC 1: Request homepage and waits for first byte
- PC 2: Request homepage on PC1: instant result
- PC 3: Request homepage on PC1: instant result
- PC 1: Finally receive the homepage after 2minutes.

What i ruled out:

- Coding issue: would be slow everywhere
- IIS issue: would be slow everywhere
- Browser issue: happens in Firefox, Chrome and Edge
- Parsing issue: content-type is text/plain
- DNS issue: Access via IP address has same problem

I have no idea what else I can look for.

Comment: What does the network setup look like? Are you using any kind of authentication that might take time? What addresses are you using to access the site locally? From your description it would appear it's rather infrequent that the problem exists locally as there are times when it doesn't happen. Is there any kind of special load on the machine? What other processes does it run? Is that site the only site hosted on it?

Comment: It happens all the time on some pages (always the same) and it never happens on some other pages (also always the same). But everything is processed before `Application_PreSendRequestContent` (Authentication, database, sessions, etc) and it hits that point after 100ms. See [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx). Its a development machine not doing much else. Local access with `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.190.40` is slow, access `192.168.190.40` from another PC is fast.

Comment: Do those pages change between sessions or are they really always the same? What about the memory consumption on the machine? Did you check that the Application Pool isn't getting recycled if you call those pages? If the pages don't change, is the call also fast if you first request them from a remote location instead of the local machine (i.e. you request X1 from PC2 before requesting it from PC1)?

Comment: Its not a recycle issue. Every time I call locally it has a 2min timeout and everytime I call remotely it loads instant. On first load the remote site is slower for startup obviously, but after that its fast. No matter if i call the page 10 or 100 times. If I call the page locally after 50 remote calls, local is still slow and remote is still fast

Comment: There are no changes between the pages and i have disabled authentication for all, to make sure everybody gets the same request. Also both local and remote hit the `PreSendRequestContent` in the same time matter,but after that its instant for remote and timeout for local

Comment: According to your own examples it's not always slow `PC 1: Request page X2 on PC1: instant result`. As you're requesting a local resource it's more likely that it is a Coding/IIS/Firewall Configuration issue. Also have a look at [Running sites on “localhost” is extremely slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386299/running-sites-on-localhost-is-extremely-slow). One of the suggestions is to verify your proxy settings as you might be making the request through your proxy depending on the setup. Even if you keep insisting that the event is raised, that doesn't mean it can't get stuck after it

Comment: Page X2 is always fast (local) and the homepage for example is always slow. No matter if it's the first or 10th time i request it. Because some pages are fast I ruled out firewall/dns/proxy issues as these things don't work on page level. I ruled out coding because the same page, on the same server, access remotely is fast. My code does not change for local/remote requests. Obviously it is stuck after that event, but all coding after that event is out of my reach as it's standard .NET code or IIS. I will look at your link for other suggestions, thank you.

Comment: If you have certain pages that are always fast and certain pages that are always slow if you try to access them locally, you should consider checking what those pages contain and what happens in the code. Maybe you are doing impersonation, some kind of caching or IP access check, maybe they're just really different in size. You should also check the Network tab of your favorite browser as that might give you some more information. If you don't see any kind of response it's really server side but maybe it's just slow? Maybe you're doing AJAX requests on the FE? Good luck with further diagnosis.

Comment: It turns out it was the Sophos anti-virus software. I disabled it and it was fast for all pages, Found it as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27015698/434949) on your link. Thanks @Seth

Comment: Nice that it worked out. If it did help consider upvoting that answer, if you didn't already. Otherwise ignore this comment.